# Does any one have modernizr example for border-radius, transition, border shadow and gradient example?

Tags: jquery, css, polyfills

I am searching on net but not find single place where i can check live example of  Modernizr.

Does any one have link of examples OR any http://jsfiddle.net/ demo page.

Comment: **http://css3pie.com/** - this solves 3 out of your 4 problems at least :)

Comment: Do you want an example using the tests (i.e. with Yep/Nope to load js conditinally?) or just the classes added to the body? ALA has an [example](http://d.alistapart.com/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/sample-advanced.html) of modernizr in use.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little overkill to test support for all of these properties (a browser that does not support border-radius is probably not going to support Gradients etc.) you can use `Modernizr.load` and pass an array of tests to test for support and load a file conditionally:

**JS**

```
Modernizr.load({
      test: [Modernizr.csscolumns, Modernizr.borderradius, Modernizr.transition, Modernizr.bordershadow],
      nope: 'css3pie.js', // file to be loaded if tests fail
});
```

Additionally, since a lot of these are visually related things, you are probably better suited dealing with this by using using modernizr's classes  (i.e. `no-borderadius`)  rather than loading js.

**Resources**

- [Adobe — Using Modernizr](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using-modernizr.html)
- [ALA — Taking Advantage of HTML5 and CSS3 with Modernizr](http://alistapart.com/article/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr)
- [HTML5 Doctor — Using Modernizr to detect HTML5 features and provide fallbacks](http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/)